# How to check if app is in assigned access mode without windows.aboveLockScreen extension?

Tags: uwp, kiosk-mode

I have a UWP app that has a bug in kiosk mode because `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreenMode` always returns false.

Hence I would like to be able to tell whether the app is running in kiosk mode.

`LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView()` is null when in kiosk mode, but this only works if I add the `windows.aboveLockScreen` extension to my appxmanifest file.

I want to avoid including the `windows.aboveLockScreen` extension because this places our app content in a secondary window, breaking some assumptions we make about threads.

So, is there any way to tell whether an app is running in kiosk mode without including the `windows.aboveLockScreen` extension?

---

**EDIT**

The reason why the app needs to know whether it is in full screen or not is because when navigating from our home view to another view we allow the user to set a setting for whether the new view should be full screen or not.

So our logic when navigating from the home view to the other view is more or less:

```
ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

if (setting.UseFullscreen 
    && !view.IsFullScreenMode)  // "IsFullScreenMode" is always false in kiosk mode
{
    view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    // Wait for window size to change
    // In kiosk mode window size never changes => Our app waits forever
}
```

Comment: Can I know why you need to know if the app is full screen mode?

Comment: Sure thing!  See my updated question.